# Get generic type used to extend a class

Tags: typescript

I have a class that takes a generic:

```
abstract class Base<P extends SomeType = SomeType> {
  // ...
}
```

And a class that extends it:

```
class A extends Base<SomeTypeA> {
  // ...
}
```

Its hard to describe, but basically I'm wondering if its possible with typescript to know "What is the type that class A extended Base with?"

Something like

```
type PropType = ExtendedGeneric<A> // SomeTypeA
```

Comment: You described it pretty well. :-) Question: What would you do with this information?

Comment: Currently I'm my app I'm using `A` and `SomeType` as generics a lot, and I got annoyed having to pass 2 generics everywhere when really I need only one. So I believe with this I don't need to ask for `SomeTypeA` as a generic, I can infer it from the other that I'm already passing everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional type to extract the type that was passed to `Base`

```
type ExtendedGeneric<T extends Base<any>> = T extends Base<infer P> ? P: never
type PropType = ExtendedGeneric<A> // SomeTypeA
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=34&pln=8&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EAqBPABxQG9kCp0CAhOAZwgC5lawpQBzZAXwChRJYiFBmz4iAQWQQAHpBAATWmiy5CJMhQLimIAK6YARtG48ecAyyiIwyBABs6SmvQA8ABSmyICpSNVFkAF5lUTUAPmRiHmRkAHpY5F1aOHYUYCUQCAh5bOQYdChkVMy2BCUwdGQAdwKAa1sCqAgEMDs8aORsMAALdHkACgImNwBKGOJeXh57R2RJGTlFZGcIFz8xCHEIqOQeKbA1ZABRLwVsgHFvaGAEFxxPRac6VbgQPDCI4PuF7yWVl1AMGMbgiAH5kG4dBAAG7QHgHAJuTQbILHU45eSXEo3FxbOIJdZqcRAA)

You can read more about conditional types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'm in the process of trying, something that confuses me is it seems that sometimes I'm getting back `SomeType` (which is extended by `SomeTypeA`). Is that how it is? Or could my `SomeTypeA` be too similar to `SomeType` for typescript to infer it?

Comment: @boy If you don't use the generic type in `Base` or the types are the same TS might get them mixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this method in your base:

```js
 abstract getType(): Constructible<Type>;
```

and you have to define an interface Constructible:

```js
export interface Constructible<T> {
    new (data): T;
}
```

then in your class A implement the method:

```js
class A extends Base<SomeTypeA> {
  getType(): Constructible<SomeTypeA> {
    return SomeTypeA;
  }
  // ...
}
```